# How to fetch Estimote Beacon name in iOS application?

Tags: ios, ibeacon, estimote

I have been working on Estimote SDK 3.0.1 (March 24, 2015) in which I have to fetch all beacons name which are in range. I am using a demo code provided by Estimote SDK 3.0.1.
   There is a class in Estimote SDK - `ESTBeaconConnection` which is basically used to establish connection between selected beacon and Estimore cloud which contains all info of selected beacon. This class- `ESTBeaconConnection` also contains some properties of a beacon and we can fetch those properties like name, color after successfully connection. 
But the problem is that I am getting null in 'name' property.

Answer (score 0):

`ESTBeaconConnection` is actually used to establish a connection between the iOS device and the beacon, not the Estimote Cloud.

The beacon's "name" in turn is something that you'd fetch from the Estimote Cloud.

Conclusion: the `name` property shouldn't be there in the `ESTBeaconConnection`. Bug spotted! (:

Instead, you can use the `ESTCloudManager` to [fetch beacon details](http://estimote.github.io/iOS-SDK/Classes/ESTCloudManager.html#//api/name/fetchBeaconDetails:completion:) from the Estimote Cloud—this will include the name.